# Solr JavaScript transformers and special characters (æ, ø, and å)

Tags: javascript, solr, special-characters

I am running [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) 1.4 with the [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) web server. I have a transformer, written in JavaScript in my `data-config.xml` file, that looks as follows:

```
    <script><![CDATA[
        function transform(row) {

            var itemColor = row.get('ItemColor');

            if (itemColor == 'SORT' || itemColor == 'BLACK') {
                row.put('ItemColor', 'Sort');
            }

            else if (itemColor == 'RØD' || itemColor == 'RED') {
                row.put('ItemColor', 'Rød');
        }

        return row;
    }
    ]]></script>
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to replace 'RØD' and 'RED' with 'Rød', and 'SORT' and 'BLACK' with 'Sort' before I add `itemColor` to the Solr index. ('SORT' is black and 'RØD' is red in Danish).

But for some reason the else-if part is never true, although `itemColor` has the value 'RØD'. There are no problems updating `itemColor` when the value is 'SORT' or 'BLACK'. I suspect it has something to do with special characters (Æ, Ø, and Å). I have tried with colors that contains those characters and it fails every time.

What is the solution?

Comment: Is your data-config.xml file utf8 or something else? Have you tried using unicode escapes? (`'\xD8'` instead of `'Ø'`)?

Comment: Yes - you are right. I have to do it this way for it to work.

   else if (itemColor == 'R\xD8D' || itemColor == 'r\xF8d') {
        row.put('ItemColor', 'R\xF8d');
   }